# How can I modify a 2d matrix so that predefined sums in both dimensions are satisfied?

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I'm working on optimizing production of a number of related widgets over a number of weeks.  The total quantity of each widget, and the total quantity of widgets produced each week is fixed.  By default, a few of each widget is produced each week.

For example:

```
Week:        1     2     3     4     5     Total
Widget A:   10    10    20    10    10        60
Widget B:   20    20    40    20    20       120
Widget C:   15    10     5    15    15        60
Totals:     45    40    65    45    45       240
```

However, due to overhead and setup time in the factory, I'd like the ability to reduce the number of types of widgets produced each week.  For example, I'd like the user to be able to delete a number of the weekly widget runs, like this:

```
Week:        1     2     3     4     5     Total
Widget A:   10    __    20    10    10        60
Widget B:   20    20    40    __    20       120
Widget C:   15    __     5    __    15        60
Totals:     45    40    65    45    45       240
```

Given the above input, how could I code a solution to modify the numbers produced per widget per week, so that the total quantity produced per week, and the total quantity produced per widget overall, still satisfies the original totals?

Comment: This seems a bit unclear to me. How many widgets and weeks are we talking? If your dimensions are 3x5, a simple backtracking algorithm should be able to do the job. The second table seems a bit misleading because the original weekly numbers no longer add up to the total. Can you give constraints on those? Why not just naively produce 60 of Widget A in week 5 (and so on for each other Widget)? There must be some additional constraint here to satisfy.

Comment: Is this a linear programming problem? Find the zero matrix entries zero, and find values for the other entries at least their current values, so as to provide the original row and column totals?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it, including a code attempt. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any error messages.